# Benefit from using ehcache in a hibernate webapp

Tags: performance, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I'm working on a webapp which is used by multiple user at the same time (on the same objects). I'm using spring and hibernate for DI and persistence. Now I'm considering adding ehcache to the family, mostly just to learn more about it and how to implement it in a existing system.

Basic questions:

1. How can I, using ehcache, be 100% sure that users always get the newest version of an entity?
2. Will ehcache be a benefit in a system where most entities are changed often?
3. If the benefit is minor (lets say 3% performance improvement), is it even worth the while to do it? - are there other benefits, aside from potential performance gains?

Not looking for code examples, just some word of advice and guidance from people who have tried to implement ehcache in an existing spring/hibernate application.